# how to remove a diagonal  line in the cube from matlab?

Tags: matlab, cube

I have drawn a cube in a scatter3 plot, quite unexpectedly, there is a diagonal line in the cube, is there anyway to remove it?

the code to draw the cube is like below:

```
vertices = [ ...
-600 -300 -100;
-100 -300 -100;
-100 200 -100;
-600 200 -100;
-600 -300 400;
-100 -300 400;
-100 200 400;
-600 200 400;
];

faces = [ ...
1 2 6 5;
2 3 7 8;
3 4 8 7;
4 1 5 8;
1 2 3 4;
5 6 7 8];

patch('Vertices',vertices,'Faces',faces,'FaceAlpha',0)
```

[image]

Comment: [Not sure if this will help of not.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/20316) <-- It is a link don't worry =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second row in the `faces` matrix should read

```
2 3 7 6;
```